# Getting subdomain to redirect and follow CNAME

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, subdomain, cname

i have migrated a domain from olddomain.com to newdomain.com...i want all URLs to redirect from olddomain.com to newdomain.com. I got this part working. My issue now is that I have a CNAME on newdomain for help.newdomain.com -> externaldomain.com (uses referrerURL to land on proper page)
I need to redirect help.olddomain.com -> help.newdomain.com -CNAME-> externaldomain.com
Is this possible with .htaccess rewrite? if not, is there another way to skin it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a 301 `.htaccess` rewrite should do it. Put this in the server that currently serves `help.olddomain.com`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^help.olddomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://externaldomain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

If you really want it to hit `help.newdomain.com` first, use that in the `RewriteRule` instead.